# How can I click on a button when it becomes visible in Gmail?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have written a Tampermonkey script to **auto-click on the little arrow of gmail "send as"**  when the composer window is open.

[image: "send as" arrow]

Two things don't seem to work:

1. The observer will resolve the promise only once (so it seems this will work only once, for the first time the composer window is open). I have tried to remove `observer.disconnect();` but it won't help.
2. The `.click()` itself is not working (not even from regular Chrome console when calling `element.click()`).

**Is there a way to make this work?**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  some script
// @author       You
// @match        http*://mail.google.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=tampermonkey.net
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    async function waitForElement(selector) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
            }

            const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
                if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                    resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                    observer.disconnect();
                }
            });

            observer.observe(document.body, {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true
            });
        });
    }

    waitForElement('.nH.Hd[role=dialog]').then(button => {
        console.log('Compose window is open');
        console.log(button.querySelector('.J-J5-Ji.J-JN-M-I-JG'));

        const downEvt = new MouseEvent("mousedown");
        button.dispatchEvent(downEvt);
    })
})();
```

Comment: Stupid question, but where is that "send as" arrow? I can't seem to find it :)

Comment: @double-beep https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Comment: Do you also want to auto-click on visibility change or only when it is appended to the DOM?

Comment: @double-beep I just want the dropdown "send as" to be open when the compose window is open (or to make it mandatory to click before clicking "send")

Answer (score 1):

Do consider making the selectors more stable - the ones you use are bound to change.

The script below uses [`waitForKeyElements`](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891/), a utility developed by [Brock Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams). The third parameter (`false`) continues to search for new elements even after the first one has been found.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  some script
// @author       You
// @match        http*://mail.google.com/*
// @require      https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BrockA/2625891/raw/waitForKeyElements.js
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* globals waitForKeyElements */

(function() {
    waitForKeyElements('.nH.Hd[role=dialog] .J-J5-Ji.J-JN-M-I-JG', element => {
        const downEvt = new MouseEvent("mousedown");
        const parent = element[0].parentElement;

        // for stability
        if (!parent.innerText.includes("one of your emails")) return;

        parent.dispatchEvent(downEvt);
    }, false);
})();
```

Comment: My code looks exactly like yours but it won't work (as "one of my emails" I put the default one which is displayed and part of the innerHtml in fact). I usde `.nH.Hd` selector, only difference. interenstingly waitForKeyELements callback doesn't get called at all (though the script itself is executed)

Comment: nothing happens with this code (even if the script is executed, waitForElements is never triggered)

Comment: @dragonmnl can you test if the selector is correct? (i.e. when you open the compose box, does running `document.querySelector('.nH.Hd[role=dialog] .J-J5-Ji.J-JN-M-I-JG')` in the console return anything?)

Comment: This works (note I have replaced `element[0]` with `element` since that errors) and returns "true" (yet the waitForKeyElements callback is not triggered): 
document.querySelector('.nH.Hd[role=dialog] .J-J5-Ji.J-JN-M-I-JG').parentElement.innerText.includes("at@mymail")